# How to create image button distributed in every cell of gridview

Tags: android

Anyone? How can I create a dynamic image button distributed to every cell in my gridviews? I give feature below, that's the features of the app that I want to imitate. I hope you can help me guys.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGh9w.jpg)

Comment: So what is the issue? What you have tried?

Comment: The issue is I'm not good in programming coz newbie, so I want ask some advice or example to how to do it for educational purposes only.

Comment: Check [this](https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-gridview.html)